# unable to insert data in Mysql unless changing the table name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie learning php and here's a wierd issue for me.

I created a table named order, which have only 1 column: a int(1) (primary key, auto increment) (it had more columns before, I have changed the struture, but would that be a problem?)

when I try to insert data using:

```
$db=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('workroom',$db);
$sql = "insert into abc values (null)";
mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

nothing happened for the db.

But when I change the table name "order" to "abc"(or any other names, and update $sql), the insert function works.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Thanks again,

Sean

Comment: [`ORDER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word. Try not to use reserved words in table names and fields; if used, you have to put ticks around the word to "escape" it. You should also not use `mysql_`-class functions and instead use `mysqli_` or PDO, and you should be [reading errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) if they occur.

Comment: Thanks Jared, that's very helpful, I haven't realized the reversed word, should be more careful..

Comment: You should mark this question as answered. Try and keep up with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still very new to PHP, but I believe order is a command for MySQL. So, to get past this error you need to include `` around your TableName or change your table name.

This might work for you.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TableName` (value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')";
```

FYI, The `` key is above "tab" key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using simply "order", you must use back-ticks on the table that you want to use so MySQL recognizes it as a table and NOT a reserved word:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` VALUES...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use table name order because its is reserved word.If you want to use order then you can simply add quotes ``

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` values(Your data);
```